# How to plot vectors without arrow heads

Tags: svg, vector, png, gnuplot

I'm trying to make a plot of hit start/end time by thread for a web application server with gnuplot.

What I want to get is time across the X-axis.  Each request to the app server is represented by a line segment where the X-coordinates of the segment represent the start and end of the request.  The Y-coordinate corresponds to the thread.

I cobbled together a little perl script to transform the thread names into distinct integers and I got mostly what I'm after.  However, it seems that the '''with vectors''' does not honor the '''arrowstyle nohead''' for either the '''svg''' or '''png''' terminals (although it is honored for the windows terminal).

So I can mostly get what I want, except that I can't get rid of the arrowheads.

Comment: Please show sample code. What scripting library are you using? If you're not using any, please show rendered SVG markup.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned I am using gnuplot5.2

Comment: @MarkZellers, is your question answered? Any kind of reponse is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked gnuplot help? Check `help vectors` and `help arrow`.

**Code:**

```
### plot with vectors and arrowhead
reset session

set samples 11
set xrange[0:2]
plot '+' u (rand(0)):(rand(0))  :(rand(0)):(rand(0)) w vectors nohead ti "nohead", \
     '+' u (rand(0)):(rand(0)+2):(rand(0)):(rand(0)) w vectors head ti "head", \
     '+' u (rand(0)):(rand(0)+4):(rand(0)):(rand(0)) w vectors heads ti "heads"
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]